# b-modal popup on script element of different component, how to show modal?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 components, 1 that handles a table `<b-table>` and 1 of that handles a bootstrap modal `<b-modal>`

Table.vue looks as follows:

```
<template>
  <b-container fluid>
    <b-row>
      <b-col md="24">
        <b-table show-empty responsive hover
          :items="items"
          :fields="fields"
          :current-page="currentPage"
          :per-page="perPage"
          :filter="filter"
          fixed="fixed"
          @row-clicked="clickRow"
          class="text-center"
          tdClass="align-middle">

          <template slot="manage_column" slot-scope="row">
            <p class="p-0 m-0"><a href="#">Edit</a><span class="d-inline-block p-2">|</span><a href="#">Renew</a></p>
            <p class="p-0 m-0" v-show="hoverIndex === row.index"><span>...</span></p>
          </template>

        </b-table>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row>
        <b-col md="24" class="my-1">
          <b-pagination :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" class="my-0" />
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <SlideModal :show="this.show ? true : false" />
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
import SlideModal from '../lib/SlideModal.vue'
const items = [
  {
    manage_column: '',
    name_column: 'John Doe',
    address_column: '123 W. Oak Ln.'
  },
  {
    manage_column: '',
    name_column: 'Jane Doe',
    address_column: '123 W. Oak Ln.'
  },
  {
    manage_column: '',
    name_column: 'Row Doe',
    address_column: '123 W. Oak Ln.'
  },
  {
    manage_column: '',
    name_column: 'Joe Doe',
    address_column: '123 W. Oak Ln.'
  },
  {
    manage_column: '',
    name_column: 'Jack Doe',
    address_column: '123 W. Oak Ln.'
  },
  {
    manage_column: '',
    name_column: 'Jill Doe',
    address_column: '123 W. Oak Ln.'
  },
  {
    manage_column: '',
    name_column: 'Jamie Doe',
    address_column: '123 W. Oak Ln.'
  }
]
export default {
  name: 'TableViewListing',
  components: {
    SlideModal
  },
  data () {
    return {
      items: items,
      fields: {
        address_column: {
          label: 'Address'
        },
        name_column: {
          label: 'Name'
        },
        manage_column: {
          label: 'Manage'
        }
      },
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 3,
      totalRows: items.length,
      pageOptions: [ 5, 10, 15 ],
      filter: null,
      hoverIndex: null,
      showModal: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onFiltered (filteredItems) {
      this.totalRows = filteredItems.length
      this.currentPage = 1
    },
    clickRow (record, index, event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      let clickedEle = event.target
      this.showModal = false
      if (clickedEle.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        /*********/
        /* Action Link was clicked, trigger Action Link Modal here... */
        /*********/
        console.log('clicked an a tag most likely in actions column.')
        alert('You clicked on the Action: ' + clickedEle.innerText)
      } else if (clickedEle.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'button') {
        /*********/
        /* Row was clicked, trigger Row Modal here... */
        /*********/
        console.dir(this)
        this.show = true

        console.log('showModal = ' + this.showModal)

        console.log('Clicked on a Row, not a button or an a tag.')
        console.log(index)
        console.dir(record)
        alert('You clicked on the Global Row Element...')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Than I am trying to hook in the click event on the Table Row via `clickRow` method to open up the Modal in SlideModal.vue here:

```
<template>
  <b-modal ref="myModalRef" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
    <div class="d-block text-center">
      <h3>Hello From My Modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <b-btn class="mt-3" variant="outline-danger" block @click="hideModal(this.show)">Close Me</b-btn>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SlideModal',
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  props: {
    show: {
      default: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showModal (val) {
      console.log('showModal triggered')
      console.log(val)
      this.$refs.myModalRef.show()
    },
    hideModal (val) {
      console.log('hideModal triggered')
      console.log(val)
      this.$refs.myModalRef.hide()
    }
  }
}
</script>


<style>

</style>
```

Ok, this is still new to me I admin, but I feel like the modal should be showing on click here.  Though, how do I send a click event to another component in vue?

The reason I'd like this to be different components, because eventually I am wanting to make this `SlideModal.vue` file handle different content for different pages and would like to pass more than just the `show` property to it.

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

In `Table.vue` you have `this.show = true` in the clickRow method, yet Table.vue doesn't have a data variable called `show`.
You do however have a variable called `showModal` which you don't use (atleast for what I can see).

In Table.vue change your code from

```
<SlideModal :show="this.show ? true : false" />
```

To

```
<SlideModal :show="this.showModal" />
```

And in the `clickRow` method change your code from

```
console.dir(this)
this.show = true
```

To

```
console.dir(this)
this.showModal = true
```

**EDIT:** For your SlideModal to work, I think you need to change it to:

```
<template>
  <b-modal ref="myModalRef" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
    <div class="d-block text-center">
      <h3>Hello From My Modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <b-btn class="mt-3" variant="outline-danger" block @click="this.show = false">Close Me</b-btn>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SlideModal',
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  props: {
    show: {
      default: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    show (newVal) {
      if(newVal) {
        this.$refs.myModalRef.show();
      } else {
        this.$refs.myModalRef.hide();
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to help a little, but the Modal is still not showing.  What about inside of the SlideModal.vue file?  Is the connection to the `showModal` method working properly?

Comment: @SolomonClosson I have edited my answer, please have a look at it again :)

Comment: Thank You so much, this was a huge headache for me for some reason.  I got it working by playing with it a little and used `v-model="show"` on the `b-modal` object instead and kept the methods as is.  Actually, with that approach the `showModal` method wasn't even needed.

Comment: Just noticed this only shows the modal 1 time, doesn't show the modal on when I hide it and try to reopen it... :(

Comment: Try changing `this.showModal = true` in the method clickRow of Table.vue to: `this.$refs.myModalRef.show();`. See if that works

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example with two different files.  The **Parent** file contains the calling code.  The component file "AddUser.vue" has the modal code.

**Parent File**

```
<template>
    <b-button v-b-modal.userModal>Open User Modal</b-button>
    <user-modal/>   <!-- this is important or you will keep on getting errors -->
</template>

<script>
import UserModal from "@/components/UserModal.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        UserModal
    }
}
```

**UserModal.vue**

```
<template>
    <b-modal id="userModal" title="User Modal">
        <p class="my-4">Testing Bootstrap Modal</p>
    </b-modal>
</template>
```

The way this works is by including the modal component in your view using **import** and then referencing that within your template code.